# I have two condition of login redirect in laravel either same page or dashboard | Laravel

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, redirect

How can I redirect after login,There are two conditions of login redirection either it should be returned on the dashboard if user goto direct login page or redirect same page ( like a cart or something)

In LoginController

```
   public function redirectTo(){
    if (request()->has('previous')) {
        $this->redirectTo = request()->get('previous');
     }
     return $this->redirectTo ?? '/dashboard';
   }
```

but how can I set url previously?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `redirect()->intended('dashboard')`.

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#authenticating-users):

> The intended method on the redirector will redirect the user to the
>   URL they were attempting to access before being intercepted by the
>   authentication middleware. A fallback URI may be given to this method
>   in case the intended destination is not available.